# Flutter BottomNavigationBar Border?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to have the shadow of the BottomNavigationBar darker and more visible. I normally do this by adding a border but I somehow can't at this point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share your code and lets us know what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

This is how you add a border to `BottomNavigationBar`

```
() => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
            ),
            builder: (context) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    blurRadius: 20.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
                    spreadRadius: 5.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
                    offset: Offset(
                      10.0, // horizontal, move right 10
                      10.0, // vertical, move down 10
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

also take a look at box shadow this might have the effect you want